# Loop to find multiple minimum and maximum values

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a table (tblProduct) with a field (SerialNum).

I am trying to find multiple minimum and maximum values from the field SerialNum, or better put: ranges of sequential serial numbers.

The serial numbers are 5 digits and a letter. Most of the values are sequential, but NOT all!

I need the output for a report to look something like:

00001A  -  00014A
00175A  -  00180A
00540A  -  00549A
12345A  -  12349A
04500B  -  04503B
04522B -   04529B
04595B
04627B  -  04631B

If the values in-between are present.

I tried a loop, but I realized I was using record sets. I need one serial num to be compared to ALL the ranges. Record sets were looking at one range.

I have been able to determine the max and min of the entire series, but not of each sequential group.

```
| SerialNum | 
| -------- | 
| 00001A| 
| 00002A| 
| 00003A| 
| 00004A| 
| 00005A| 
| 00006A| 
| 00007A| 
| 00008A| 
| 00009A| 
| 00010A| 
| 00011A| 
| 00012A| 
| 00013A| 
| 00014A| 
| 00175A| 
| 00176A| 
| 00177A| 
| 00178A| 
| 00179A| 
| 00180A| 
| 00540A| 
| 00541A| 
| 00542A| 
| 00543A| 
| 00544A| 
| 00545A| 
| 00546A| 
| 00547A| 
| 00548A| 
| 00549A| 
| 12345A| 
| 12346A| 
| 12347A| 
| 12348A| 
| 12349A| 
| 04500B| 
| 04501B| 
| 04502B| 
| 04503B| 
| 04522B| 
| 04523B| 
| 04524B| 
| 04525B| 
| 04526B| 
| 04527B| 
| 04528B| 
| 04529B| 
| 04595B| 
| 04627B| 
| 04628B| 
| 04629B| 
| 04630B| 
| 04631B|
```

Comment: Post your VBA loop

Answer (score 0):

Try to *group by* the number found with `Val`:

```sql
Select 
    Min(SerialNum) As MinimumSerialNum,
    Max(SerialNum) As MaximumSerialNum
From
    tblProduct
Group By
    Val(SerialNum)
```

Comment: The above code generates the following results: MinimumSerialNum MaximumSerialNum
00001A 00001A
00002A 00002A                                                                                                                                     I modified to: `SELECT min(left([serialnum],5)) AS minimumserialnum, Max(left([serialnum],5)) AS maximumserialnum, right([serialnum],1) AS letter FROM tblProduct GROUP BY right([serialnum],1);` and got: minimumserialnum maximumserialnum letter
00001 12349  A
04500 04505  B      Not exactly what I need. I am missing the gaps in the A set.

Comment: Can’t tell without sample data.

Comment: I need to find all the minimum and maximums that are sequential based on the number and grouped by the last letter.    When I tried a loop it either pull nothing or everything.  My logic is off on how to ask it to find and sort. I will try to post the loop later.

Comment: Still, without neither sample data, nor your "loop", we can't help. As is, I mus admit, that I don't know what you are asking for.